# How to modify a child entry in a mongoDB

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I've got a collection of forum posts, looking (roughly) like

```
{
"author": author,
"date": new Date(),
"content": req.body.content,
"comments":{
    "deleted": 0,
    "author": author,
    "date": new Date(),
    "content": req.body.content
     }
}
```

if a user adds a comment, it is simply $pushed on to the current comments.

Now i want a possibility to delete one specific comment.
I inserted the "deleted" flag to review the comments as admin, rather than just completely deleting them.

but the problem is: how do i tell mongoDB which exact comment i want to delete?

I have just now added an "commentID" field, but i can't figure out how to auto-increment it (the documentation is really strange about this),
after having tried a lot of stuff like "comments.toDeleteId" or "comments[toDeleteId]" in the query.

TLDR: how can i query post "34563456354", comment "5", $set "deleted" to "1", where the comments are an array themselves?

thanks

### EDIT

this is the console.dir of a post:

```
{_id: //etc etc
op: 'Anonymous',
postContent: 'testtest',
createdAt: //etc,
comments:
[ { deleted: 0,
    posted: //etc,
    author: 'Anonymous',
    comment: 'test' },
  { deleted: 0,
    posted: //etc,
    author: 'Anonymous',
    comment: 'testtesttest' } ]
```

Comment: is `comments` array or object?

Comment: i just checked, it is indeed an array, containing objects. i'll update the console.dir in the question

Comment: You should probably use another collection for Comments, and then just populate the forum posts with it.

Comment: is there no way to just insert an auto-incrementing field? that would solve my problem. like "push it onto comments, increment ID, thank you"?

Comment: @PaulSchneider here some confusion what you want to set `deleted:1` where `comment: 'testtesttest'` ? or you want to push new object in `comments` array? or increase `deleted` to 1 where `comment: 'testtesttest'`?

Comment: i want to update an existing comment. setting "deleted" from 0 to 1.
but i have to find the index of the comment dynamically

Comment: Read the tag descriptions before adding a tag!

Answer (score 1):

Use [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) in update as below :

```
db.collectioName.update({
"_id": ObjectId("55ba6729eb5f4a21914568df"),
"comments": {
    "$elemMatch": {
        "comment": "testtesttest"
    }
}
}, {
"$set": {
    "comments.$.deleted": 1
}
})
```

Or If you want to increment the `deleted` then use [$inc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) as :

```
db.collectionName.update({
"_id": ObjectId("55ba6729eb5f4a21914568df"),
"comments": {
    "$elemMatch": {
        "comment": "testtesttest"
    }
}
}, {
"$inc": {
    "comments.$.deleted": 1
}
})
```

And If you want to push new object in `comment` then use `$push` in update as :

```
db.collectionName.update({
"_id": ObjectId("55ba6729eb5f4a21914568df")
}, {
"$push": {
    "comments": {
        "deleted": 1,
        "posted": new Date(),
        "author": "ABC",
        "comment": "tests"
    }
}
})
```

Comment: but i wanted to delete comments by their INDEX. like "delete the third comment". see below for the solution that worked, thanks for the effort though. i'm gonna be looking into $elemMatch, this looks promising for some things i have planned.

Answer (score 0):

i have actually found a way to do this, even though i had searched before and did not find that thread.

the way to do it is actually quite simple, yet hard to grasp at first.

```
var selector = {};
var operator = {};
selector['comments.' + commentId + '.deleted'] = 1;
operator['$set'] = selector;
```

this gave me a

```
{'$set': {'comments.2.deleted': 1 } }
```

which i could easily insert into the query  where

```
{_id: thisId,
operator,
cb)
```

(credits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/19115944/4547337 )