# How do I use dynamic content in the $ set data section MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, backend

I use the findOneAndUpdate function to update the data.
 I want the number 0 in the section

`$ set: {"experience.0.title": newExpUpdate.title,`

can be replaced by the use variable.
this my code. 
    `Profile.findOneAndUpdate(
    { currentUser: req.user.id },
    {
      $set: {
      "experience.0.title": req.body.title,
      "experience.0.company": req.body.company,
      "experience.0.location": req.body.location,
      }
    },
    { new: true }).then(newExp => res.json(newExp));`

How can I do that?

I have to do this because The experience is an array. If the experience needs to be edited in the second position in the array then my code should be

```
"experience.2.title": req.body.title
```

many thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [update nth document in a nested array document in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389195/update-nth-document-in-a-nested-array-document-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to find an item in the experience array. Is that correct? If the item doesn't exist then insert the item at the end.

To do that, you use the $elemMatch evaluation.

```
{ currentUser: req.user.id,
  experience: {
      $elemMatch: { title: req.body.title, company: req.body.company, location: req.body.company
  }
},
    {
      $set: {
      "experience.$.title": req.body.title,
      "experience.$.company": req.body.company,
      "experience.$.location": req.body.location,
      }
    },
    { new: true }).then(newExp => res.json(newExp));
```

Comment: Two issues here: 1) a copy paste error: `location: req.body.company` should be `location: req.body.location` and 2) this query would update an array element to the same values that it already contains...

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
n = 1
update = {}
update["experience." + n + ".title"] = req.body.title
update["experience." + n + ".company"] = req.body.company
update["experience." + n + ".location"] = req.body.location

Profile.findOneAndUpdate(
    { currentUser: req.user.id },
    {
      $set: update
    },
    { new: true }).then(newExp => res.json(newExp));
```